# "cannot find symbol" error for deleteCharAt() method even though I imported java.lang.*

Tags: java

I'm a very beginner `JAVA` coder, and this question might be really naive, but as the question states, my code keeps giving me errors for not being able to find `deleteCharAt()`. I'd really appreciate some insight! Here's my code

```java
    package hw5;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.*; 

    public class Business {
      String businessID;
      String businessName;
      String businessAddress;
      String reviews;
      int reviewCharCount;


      // Constructor for the Business Class
      public Business (String s) {
        String[] temp = s.split(", "); // splits the string by a comma and space
        businessID = temp[0]; // stores first index into business ID
        businessID.deleteCharAt(0); // delete the { 
        businessName = temp[1]; // stores 2nd index into businessName 
        businessAddress = temp[2]; // stores 3rd index into businessName 
        reviews = temp [3]; // tores 4th index into businessName
        reviews.deleteCharAt(reviews.length()-1); // delete the last }
        reviewCharCount = reviews.length(); // input character # into reviewCharCount
      }

      public List reviewList() {
        String[] temp = this.reviews.split(" "); // make reviews into an array
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(temp); // make array into a list 
        Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator(); // initializes iterator for list
        while (itr.hasNext()) { // iterates over the whole list 
          String uniqueWord = itr.next(); // store next element into string
          // if the string equals a nonimportant word 
          if (uniqueWord.equals("a") || uniqueWord.equals("the") || uniqueWord.equals("is") || uniqueWord.equals("and")) { 
            list.remove(uniqueWord); // remove the word
          }
        }
        return list; // returns list 
      }

      public String toString() {
        return "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
              + "Business ID: " + businessID + "\n"
              + "Business Name: " + businessName + "\n"
              + "Business Address: " + businessAddress + "\n"
              //+ "Reviews: " + reviews + "\n"
              + "Character Count: " + reviewCharCount;
      }
    }
```

Comment: This problem shows why it's a good idea to use an IDE for Java, it would have showed you your mistake right away.

Comment: I don't believe there is a string method called deleteCharAt().

Answer (score 6):

Because there isn't a [`String.deleteCharAt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) method. There **is** a [`StringBuilder.deleteCharAt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#deleteCharAt-int-) method. Change

```
String businessID;
```

to

```
StringBuilder businessID;
```

and

```
businessID = temp[0];
```

to

```
businessID = new StringBuilder(temp[0]);
```

And the same everywhere else you want to use `deleteCharAt(int)`. Once done, if needed, you can call `toString()` on the `StringBuilder` and get an **immutable** `String`.